# Kamailio '403 Not Relaying' when default port changed

Tags: sip, nat, sip-server, kamailio

Hello fellow developers...

We have been testing Kamailio for a week and it is working great...
But some of the our friends reported that they can't connect to our server using their mobile Internet... and it seems default SIP port is blocked by Service Provider...

So we decided to change ports...
I opened kamailio.cfg and added these lines:

```
listen=tcp:_PUBLIC_IP_:32850
listen=udp:_PUBLIC_IP_:32850
listen=tls:_PUBLIC_IP_:32851
listen=tcp:127.0.0.1:32850
listen=udp:127.0.0.1:32850
listen=tls:127.0.0.1:32851
listen=tcp:10.19.0.5:32850
listen=udp:10.19.0.5:32850
listen=tls:10.19.0.5:32851

port=32850
port=32851
```

Now clients throwing an error "403 Not relaying"...
I tried to enable debugging to see cfgtrace... no errors detected
But when I comment out lines above, (with default cfg) everything works fine

Where and What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have sent an [email](http://lists.sip-router.org/pipermail/sr-users/2015-December/090996.html) regarding this issue, and received [solution](http://lists.sip-router.org/pipermail/sr-users/2015-December/090998.html) for this problem..

> Most probably the r-uri is without port, being considered 5060, but then, if kamailio is not listening on port 5060, it will not consider domains/ips without port as being for it, so it will try to forward it to port 5060. 
>   You can eventually listen on both port 5060 and another higher port. Or add alias=ip:5060 parameters.
>   Cheers,
>   Daniel

Answer (score 2):

If you are changing default port for security reasons, then there is no point in configuring kamailio to listen on 2 ports ( including default port ) as they mentioned in the solution. I solved this by adding below line in REGISTER section. My kamailio is acting as proxy and my sip client is sending register message without port number. So kamailio sending back "403 Not relaying".

I closed 5060 port, so any external client which does not know my new port number can not send SIP message to default port. If a blank port or 5060 port exist in  SIP message and recievd on new port then i am changing $ru like below.

```
if (($ru = "sip:$rU@my_kamailio_IP:5060" )||($ru = "sip:$rU@my_kamailio_IP"))
{
  $ru = "sip:$rU@my_kamailio_IP:NewPort";
}
```